# Has anyone successfully used Google's WindowBuilder Eclipse plugin to build a UI that includes JFreeChart components?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jfreechart, windowbuilder

If so, what kinds of setup/configuration needs to be done? I'm currently poking around with no luck yet. It's not a requirement, but I have had good luck with building standard Swing interfaces with WindowBuilder, so I'd like to go further and include JFreeChart components with them. I could jump into the code editor, but it would just be nice to have everything graphical, at least for laying out windows.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to add the JFreeChart controls by hand.  Here's an example of adding a two ECG panels to the main ECGPanel.  Since there is no empty ChartPanel constructor adding this to the palette manager didn't seem possible.

```
    XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    ChartPanel TopECGPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    TopECGPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    TopECGPanel.setMouseZoomable(true);
    //setContentPane(chartPanel);
    TopECGPanel.setBounds(10, 41, 917,209);
    ECGPanel.add(TopECGPanel);

    XYDataset dataset2 = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart2 = createChart(dataset2);
    ChartPanel BottomECGPanel = new ChartPanel(chart2);
    BottomECGPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    BottomECGPanel.setMouseZoomable(true);
    //setContentPane(chartPanel);
    BottomECGPanel.setBounds(10, 275, 917,226);
    ECGPanel.add(BottomECGPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Swing JavaBean component can be easily added to the WindowBuilder palette which is highly customizable...

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/userinterface/palette_manager.html

Comment: This looks promising. I'll check it out when I get some time. ChartPanel (which is the JFreeChart class that you add various charts to) is a JPanel, so I should be able to at least get that added. That should be a good start.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Did you ever manage to do this? I tried importing .jar but all the components have "demo" at the end which doesn't seem right